# Add a border around the region by inserting a given character

Tags: text-editing, region

There's here, for example, given text:

```
WASP-41b        0.94    1.18    3.052404        0.04    1244    transit 590     0.93    5545

WASP-42b        0.527   1.122   4.9816819       0.0561          transit 520     0.95    5315

WASP-47b        1.21    1.15    4.16071         0.052   1275    transit 650     1.11    5576

WASP-49b        0.378   1.115   2.7817387       0.0379          transit 550     0.94    5600

WASP-52b        0.46    1.27    1.7497798       0.0272          transit 460     0.87    5000

WASP-54b        0.636   1.653   3.6936411       0.04987         transit 650     1.21    6100

WASP-55b        0.627   1.335   4.4656291       0.0558  1290    transit 1100    1.16    6070

WASP-56b        0.571   1.092   4.617101        0.05458         transit 830     1.03    5600

WASP-57b        0.644   1.05    2.83891856      0.03769         transit 1480    0.89    5600
```

Want to modify `buffer` text around given marked `region` with some character, turning it as:

```
WASP-41b        0.94    1.18    3.052404        0.04    1244    transit 590     0.93    5545

WASP-42b        0.527   1.122   4.9816819       0.0561          transit 520     0.95    5315

WASP-47b        1.21    1.15    4.16071         0.052   1275    transit 650     1.11    5576
                              ***********************************************               
WASP-49b        0.378   1.115 * 2.7817387       0.0379          transit 550 *   0.94    5600
                              *                                             *               
WASP-52b        0.46    1.27  * 1.7497798       0.0272          transit 460 *   0.87    5000
                              *                                             *               
WASP-54b        0.636   1.653 * 3.6936411       0.04987         transit 650 *   1.21    6100
                              *                                             *               
WASP-55b        0.627   1.335 * 4.4656291       0.0558  1290    transit 1100*   1.16    6070
                              ***********************************************               
WASP-56b        0.571   1.092   4.617101        0.05458         transit 830     1.03    5600

WASP-57b        0.644   1.05    2.83891856      0.03769         transit 1480    0.89    5600
```

That seems to be very simple, but would like to know how to do it.

Any idea?

Comment: Command `boxquote-region`, from library [`boxquote.el`](https://github.com/davep/boxquote.el) doesn't do quite what you want, but it does put the left part of a box around the region. Perhaps you can use some of its code as inspiration, if you don't get a direct answer here.

Comment: See also `picture-mode`, which might help, either directly or by leveraging some of its code.

Comment: Just made it, @Drew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in [ibm-box-drawing-hydra.el](https://gist.github.com/jasonm23/4fc09e7a20e55ec21bc834658d0545b6#file-ibm-box-drawing-hydra-el) library, maybe isn't exactly what is seeked, but gives a north.